# Hide overflow in a position relative container

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a problem, I made a beautiful button with snake effect but I need a last thing, I need to hide overflow to make the snake effect.

there is my button:

[image: button]

I want to hide theses parts, with `overflow: hidden;` this works with `position: absolute;` but not with relative.

```css
body {
    padding: 30px;
}

.btn-order {
    position: relative;;
    background-color: #961a22;
    color: #ff7675;
    padding: 30px 60px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-order:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
}

.btn-order span:nth-child(1) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #ff3a3a);
    animation: animate1 1.25s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
    0% {
       transform: translateX(-100%); 
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(100%); 
     }
}

.btn-order span:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #ff3a3a);
    animation: animate2 1.25s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.625s;
}

@keyframes animate2 {
    0% {
       transform: translateY(-100%); 
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(100%); 
     }
}

.btn-order span:nth-child(3) {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #ffffff, #ff3a3a);
    animation: animate3 1.25s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate3 {
    0% {
       transform: translateX(100%); 
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%); 
     }
}

.btn-order span:nth-child(4) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff, #ff3a3a);
    animation: animate4 1.25s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.625s;
}

@keyframes animate4 {
    0% {
       transform: translateY(100%); 
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-100%); 
     }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn-order">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    COMMANDER
</a>
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: `display: inline-block;` or block to the btn

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif it works but why my button moved in my container ?

Comment: Ok there was no problem, I had added some bullshit, thank you so much !

Answer (score -1):

Increasing the body width can fix it.